# Question about how the determinant of a square matrix can help determine whether a set of vectors is a basis.

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a linear algebra midterm tomorrow. While it's highly unlikely a question of this type shows up, I really wanted to understand this because I am curious since I've spent so long without coming up with an answer.

Let $a, b, c, d \in \mathbb{R}$. Prove that the set $$\bigg\{\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}\bigg\}$$ is a basis for $\mathbb{R^2}$ iff $ad-bc\neq0$.

(If anyone is planning to write a proof, can they assume no knowledge of inverse matrices, determinants, or anything of that sort)

Comment: In general, if you wanna check whether a set of n vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ form a basis, put them in a matrix as columns. If the determinant is nonzero then they are linearly independent and form a basis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A partial proof:

Let $\lambda_1,\ \lambda_2$ be such that

$$\lambda_1[a,c]+\lambda_2[b,d]=0$$

now we have

$$\lambda_1a+\lambda_2b = 0,\ \lambda_1c+\lambda_2d = 0$$

if $c\neq 0$, multiplying the second equation by ($a/c$) and substracting gives

$$\lambda_2(b-d\cdot a/c)=0$$

In this case, $\lambda_2=0$ is the only solution if and only if

$$(b-d\cdot a/c)=0 \Leftrightarrow ad-bc=0$$

On the other hand, if $c=0$, $\lambda_1=\lambda_2=0$ is the only solution if $a=0$ or $d=0$. Either way, this gives

$$ ad-bc=0$$

Answer (score 1):

I guess you meant the set $\;\{(a,b)\,,\,(c,d)\}\;$ . In general, two vectors in any vector space are linearly dependent iff one of them is a scalar multiple of the other one, so we can do

$$\{(a,b)\,,\,(c,d)\}\;\;\text{linearly dependent iff there exists}\;x\in\Bbb R\;\;s.t. (a,b)=(xc,xd) \;\text{iff} $$

$$\det\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}=det\begin{pmatrix}xc&xd\\c&d\end{pmatrix}=x\cdot\det\begin{pmatrix}c&d\\c&d\end{pmatrix}=x\cdot0=0$$

Answer (score 0):

If anyone was curious about the answer: [image]